# CSS - expand div on hover and do not move other divs

Tags: html, hover, z-index, move, expand

I need to create product grid:

- With fixed div height;
- Expand - to show large texts only on div:hover;
- Do not move other divs.
- CSS

Working Sample:
**http://rozetka.com.ua/mobile-phones/c80003/filter/preset=smartfon/**

My code:
**http://jsfiddle.net/JfNsu/6/**

**CSS**

```
.product-grid {}
.item_box_in2 {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px #DDD solid;
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    height: 15em;
    overflow:hidden;}
.item_box_in2:hover {
    overflow: visible;
    height: auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="product-grid">
<!--Product 1-->
<div class="item_box_in2">    
<h1>Title 1</h1>
    <p>Text 1</p>
    <p>Price 1</p>
    <p>Desk 111111111 111111111 11111111</p>
</div>
<!--Product 2-->
<div class="item_box_in2">   
<h1>Title 2</h1>
    <p>Text 2</p>
    <p>Price 2</p>
    <p>Desk 222222222 2222222222 22222222222 222222222 222222222222 22222222222222 222222222222 222222222222222 22222222222222 22222222222222 222 222222222222 22222222222 2222222222222222 2222222222222222222222 222222 22222222222 22222222222</p>
</div>
<!--Product 3-->
<div class="item_box_in2">   
<h1>Title 3</h1>
    <p>Text 3</p>
    <p>Price 3</p>
    <p>Desk 333333333 333333333 33333333333333333 333333333333333 333333333333333 3333333333333333 33333333333333333333 33333</p>
</div>
<!--Product 1-->
<div class="item_box_in2">   
<h1>Title 1</h1>
    <p>Text 1</p>
    <p>Price 1</p>
    <p>Desk 111111111 111111111 11111111</p>
</div>
<!--Product 2-->
<div class="item_box_in2">   
<h1>Title 2</h1>
    <p>Text 2</p>
    <p>Price 2</p>
    <p>Desk 222222222 2222222222 22222222222 222222222 222222222222 22222222222222 222222222222 222222222222222 22222222222222 22222222222222 222 222222222222 22222222222 2222222222222222 2222222222222222222222 222222 22222222222 22222222222</p>
</div>
<!--Product 3-->
<div class="item_box_in2">
<h1>Title 3</h1>
    <p>Text 3</p>
    <p>Price 3</p>
    <p>Desk 333333333 333333333 33333333333333333 333333333333333 333333333333333 3333333333333333 33333333333333333333 33333</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably best giving each div a unique ID then positioning them (not with relative because it will move them when they expand) and for each ID make a hover e.g.

```
ID-TopRowBox1:hover {
    height: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
}
ID-BottomRowBox1:hover {
    height: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -9999;
}
```

I hope this helps fix your problem :)